# if heatsink deattached from northbridge does it makes any difference if it does how can be attached

Tags: northbridge

I've a mercury motherboard model PI865D7, heat sink from the north bridge got deattached.
It was fixed through some type of glue as it is appearing and it also has an angle rod to get it fixed on northbridge, which I fixed but not glued.

I want to know that it'll make any difference if which type and how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

The "glue" is actually "thermal compound". If you don't re-fit it properly, then the northbridge is likely to run hot; this will probably show up as more frequent crashes or lockups of the computer.